# [RKClient sharedClient].requestQueue and [RKObjectManager sharedManager].requestQueue is the same queue?

Tags: restkit

[RKClient sharedClient].requestQueue and [RKObjectManager sharedManager].requestQueue are the same queue?

```
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].requestQueue cancelRequestsWithDelegate:self]; 
[[RKClient sharedClient].requestQueue cancelRequestsWithDelegate:self];
```

I request by this

```
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] loadObjectsAtResourcePath:final_url usingBlock:
    ^(RKObjectLoader *loader){...}];
```

I know it seems like I should use the first one, but would the second one did the same job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are not always the same thing. The FIRST RKObjectManager to be created becomes the sharedManager and the FIRST RKClient object becomes the sharedClient.

In a normal application (one manager created at the beginning of the app lifetime) these are the same object yes.

Comment: You mean? If I create one manager and one client, the sharedClient is point to the manager?

Comment: Normally you create the manager and the client is generated automatically.